# Deserializar objeto según valores propiedad JSON c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialize

Perdonar pero ya no se donde buscar.

Tengo un programa en C# que debe pintar cierta area en un mapa.
La petición al repositorio de areas me devuelve un JSON en el que el objeto no siempre trae la misma geometría.
Dependiendo del type de geometry necesito parsear diferente puntos y poligonos.

Ejemplo de respuesta json con dos objetos con diferente type:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "AREA-1",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    38.376487,
                    27.011042
                ]
            },
            "radius": 20
        },
        {
            "_id": "AREA-2",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            38.376487,
                            27.011042
                        ],
                        [
                            38.366487,
                            27.011042
                        ],
                        [
                            38.366487,
                            27.001041999999999
                        ],
                        [
                            38.376487,
                            27.011042
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "radius": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Mi intento o aproximación:
Estoy utilizando la librería Newtonsoft

```
RootArea sasAreas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootArea>(jsonResp, jsonSerializerSettings);

public class RootArea
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<area> data { get; set; }
    }
public class area
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public double radius { get; set; }
    }
public class Geometry
    {
        public string type { get; set; }

        public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; } 
//pero claro, tan solo funciona para uno de los types: Polygon y por tanto da error en AREA-1
    }
```

Debe de haber una forma sencilla, pero no se como hacerlo, espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ya lo he comentado varias veces, pero parece que mucha gente desconoce esta funcionalidad de visual studio. Si copias tu json y en VS vas a `Editar/pegado especial/pegar json como clases` vs crea correctamente las clases necesarias para deserializar. Alternativamente, tienes servicios como [Json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @derobpe te esta dando error porque el tipo de campo coordinates no siempre es la misma lista puede variar te aconsejo que pruebes con un dynamic.

```
RootArea sasAreas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootArea>(jsonResp, 
jsonSerializerSettings);

public class RootArea
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<area> data { get; set; }
}
public class area
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public double radius { get; set; }
}
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public List<dynamic> coordinates { get; set; } 
}
```

De esta manera le estas diciendo que esperas una lista dynamica y podria funcionarte si no prueba con

```
List<object>
```

también podria funcionarte es lo que se me ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declararlo como `object`, quedando de esta manera

```
 public List<object> coordinates { get; set; }
```

tus clases quedaran de esta forma

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<object> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public int radius { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

posteriormente deserializas tu JSON

```
var resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(resp);
```

accedes a tu JSON de esta manera

```
Console.WriteLine(resultado.status);

 //"_id": "AREA-1",
    Console.WriteLine(resultado.data[0].geometry.coordinates[0]);

 //"_id": "AREA-2",
    Console.WriteLine(resultado.data[1].geometry.coordinates[0]);
```

aqui puedes ver el [ejemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xfas4T)